# Interactive interaction of selections with checkboxes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmenu

I have a popup window in which it reads in a list of options and populates it into groupbox and checkboxes.

I have a selection in which it contains the following data:
`my_selection = {'drinks': ['coffee'], 'snacks': ['m&m']}`
and I am trying to get the options - `coffee` and -`m&m` checked in the popup window.

However my selection can varies, meaning, itemA may have on of the `drinks`items, and if I select itemB (itemA is no longer in selection), it could have an item from `drinks` and 2 items in `snacks` and I had wanted to make sure the correct option is checked, in the event, if there are same item naming but in different categories or vice verse.

I tried inserting the selection case into the class as follows:

```py
class FormWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_items, my_selection, parent=None, callback=None):
        ...
        if my_selection:
            for k, v in my.items():
                for i in v:
                    if sub_chk.text() == i:
                        sub_chk.setChecked(True)
```

It only checks the latest item it found, in this case, only the items in `Snacks` is taken into account.

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from collections import defaultdict


class FormWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_items, parent=None, callback=None):
        super(FormWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.callback = callback

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.checkbox_options = []
        self.menu_tag_dict = defaultdict(set)

        for main_name, sub_name in main_items.items():
            # Set the main item
            groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self)
            groupbox.setTitle(main_name.title())
            groupbox.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
            layout.addWidget(groupbox)

            if sub_name:
                # sub_txt = [(action.text()) for action in sub_name]
                sub_txt = [action for action in sub_name]

                # Creates QCheckbox for each option
                for s in sub_txt:
                    sub_chk = QtGui.QCheckBox(s)
                    self.checkbox_options.append(sub_chk)
                    groupbox.layout().addWidget(sub_chk)

        layout.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('Form Checking')
        self.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_items = {'drinks': ['coffee', 'tea', 'water'], 'snacks': ['biscuits', 'm&m']}
    my_win = FormWindow(main_items)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# Example1 of what my selection will return
my_selection = {'drinks': ['coffee'], 'snacks': ['m&m']}

# Example2 of what my selection will return
my_selection = {'drinks': ['water', 'coffee'], 'snacks': ['biscuits']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to obtain the checked items, then what you should do is to have a reflection of the data by removing or adding the selection according to the status of the checked, in the following example, if you press the button, the checked items will be printed:

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from functools import partial


class FormWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    checkbox_options_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, main_items, parent=None, callback=None):
        super(FormWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.callback = callback

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.checkbox_options = {}

        for main_name, sub_name in main_items.items():
            groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
            groupbox.setTitle(main_name.title())
            lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(groupbox)
            layout.addWidget(groupbox)
            self.checkbox_options[main_name] = set()
            for s in sub_name:
                sub_chk = QtGui.QCheckBox(s)
                info = (main_name, s)
                wrapper = partial(self.on_stateChanged, info)
                sub_chk.stateChanged.connect(wrapper)
                lay.addWidget(sub_chk)
        layout.addStretch()
        self.setWindowTitle("Form Checking")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(tuple, QtCore.Qt.CheckState)
    def on_stateChanged(self, info, state):
        name, item = info
        option = self.checkbox_options[name]
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            option.add(item)
        else:
            if item in option:
                option.remove(item)
        self.checkbox_options_changed.emit(self.checkbox_options)

    def get_checked_items(self):
        return self.checkbox_options


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_items = {
        "drinks": ["coffee", "tea", "water"],
        "snacks": ["biscuits", "m&m"],
    }
    my_win = FormWindow(main_items)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
    button = QtGui.QPushButton("Print me")
    lay.addWidget(button)
    lay.addWidget(my_win)

    def on_clicked():
        print(my_win.get_checked_items())

    button.clicked.connect(on_clicked)
    my_win.checkbox_options_changed.connect(print)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

```
{'drinks': {'coffee', 'tea'}, 'snacks': set()}
```

[image]

```
{'drinks': {'coffee', 'tea'}, 'snacks': {'biscuits'}}
```

Comment: Hi, I am doing something similar, but instead of using the button clicked to reflect the changes, is there a way for it to reflect the changes immediately (real-time) based on selections (contains dictionary)?

Comment: @yan I have updated the code by adding the checkbox_options_changed signal that will be issued every time there is a change.